# Java server unreachable by nodejs tests in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a Jar file which need to test using NodeJs in docker.
So I used a Docker-Compose to run both from the same project folder.

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks: 
      - overlay
  test:
    build: .
    depends_on:
        - "web"
    networks: 
      - overlay
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "web:8080", "--", "npm", "test"]

networks:
  overlay:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM timbru31/java-node
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install mocha
RUN npm install chai
RUN npm install chai-http
RUN npm install mocha-junit-reporter
RUN npm install --production
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

COPY . .
CMD [ "java", "-jar" , "test-engineer-exercise-0.0.1.jar"]
```

when I run it using **docker-compose up** i get all test failed.
While i can run the tests successfully from local machine.
What is the problem here, could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my Testing file where i pointed to look for a server:
**http://localhost:8080**
But server in docker-compose was called **web**, between services serve container was exposed to **http://web:8080 instead of http://localhost:8080**
**Changed the address in tests to use web:8080 and now it works**